# Schedule a timer based service for Cordova App

Tags: html, cordova, cordova-plugins

Any Cordova plugins available for making a background service that will trigger every day at a specific time (like 6 am)?

Comment: It'll be totally depending on what event you wish to trigger. You could use background service but also you could use local, push notifications as well as firebase.

Comment: Tried https://github.com/wnyc/cordova-plugin-wakeuptimer  as it matched my requirement. However it wasn't triggering the alarm as expected plus iOS build failed! Looking up for similar plugins

Answer (score 0):

this might be a good place to start: http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/